# Linux: How to apply ICC profile to whole desktop?

Tags: linux, xorg, color-profiles, icc

I have a monitor with oversaturated red (HP LP2475w). I am able to apply ICC profile to various apps like GIMP and Firefox and Gnome.

But I'd like to apply it to everything - because e.g. Flash animations in Firefox are rendered by Flash and don't use ICC.

So, can I apply it to whole X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try xcalib

/usr/bin/xcalib -d :0 /path/to/your/icc/file.icc

http://xcalib.sourceforge.net/ - the app websit. But try to search it in your distribution package manager.

Comment: Works, thanks, however, I can't change for a single screen, only for whole display. `-s 1` says "X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)". I have nVidia TwinView enabled, so that might be the reason. Ideas?

Comment: Try something like -d :0.1, but really I have no real ideas...

Comment: Technically this only can do some of the work to correct gamma, white point in the GPU hardware. Colors may not be exactly as expected, but it's still an improvement. Ideally, xcalib has the profile loaded, and software also performs its own corrections with the 3D lookup table in the profile on top of that.

Answer (score 2):

With Oyranos and CompICC the whole desktop is corrcted in hardware. Look at http://compicc.sf.net Make sure all applications use the system profile.